# active/inactive list in linux kernel

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel, shared-memory, page-replacement

Where can I get active/inactive page lists inside Linux kernel which is maintained for memory management?
Basically I want to dump these lists' info periodically, so I could understand which pages are active/inactive?
Ultimate goal is to find which shared libraries are being actively used, and which other are not so actively.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Years late, but for anyone else who needs it:

The active/inactive lists are lru lists and have type lruvec.

On Linux 5.6 the `enum lru_lists` and the corresponding `struct lruvec` are defined in include/linux/mmzone.h.

Then, there are a few functions that I know of that return lruvec:

```
mem_cgroup_page_lruvec()
mem_cgroup_lruvec()
```